# Lists in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file of format like this

```
10:45  a  b  c
     x 0  1  2
     y 4  5  6
     z 7  8  9
```

I want to make x as key and 0,1,2 its value in the list.Same with y and z

```
 while(1):
    line = f.readline()



    if time in line:
        print (line)
        L1.append(line)
        for count,line in enumerate(f):

            if (i < 3):
                L1.append(line)
                print ("Line{} : {}".format(count,line.strip()))
                i=i+1


        #print(L1)
        for k in range(1):
            print(L1[k])
            test1 = L1[k]
            a1 = test1.split()
            print (a1[1])
            dict = {a1[1]: L1[k] for a1[1] in L1[k]}
            print (dict)

        for k in range(1,3):
            #print("hey")
            print (L1[k])               #will list the single row
            test = L1[k]                
            #print(test)                 
            a = test.split()            
            print (a[0])                
            dict = {a[0]:L1[k] for a[0] in L1[k]}
            print (dict)
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong here?
P.S. - I am new to python

Comment: What is the value of `time` ? And what problem are you facing ? What result do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
my_dict = {}
lines = f.readLines()
lines.pop(0)
for line in lines:
   line_list = line.split(' ')
   key = line_list.pop(0)
   my_dict.update({key: line_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import string
start_found = False
result_dict = {}

for line in open("stack1_input.txt", mode='r'):
    if (line.startswith("10:45")):
        start_found = True
        continue
    if start_found == True:
        values = line.split()
        if len(values) == 4:
            result_dict[values[0]] = values[1:]

print (result_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish what it is I think you need (assuming your text file is stored in the same directory and you replace 'test.txt' with your filename):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as values:
    contents = values.read().strip().split()
    new_dict = {}
    i = 4
    while i <= len(contents)-4:
        new_dict.update({contents[i]: contents[i+1:i+4]})
        i += 4

print(new_dict)
```

or this, if you want the values as integers:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as values:
    contents = values.read().strip().split()
    new_dict = {}
    i = 4
    while i <= len(contents)-4:
        new_dict.update({contents[i]: [int(contents[i+1]),int(contents[i+2]),int(contents[i+3])]})
        i += 4

print(new_dict)
```